# How to use a fixed cell in table and then a list of item below that?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using below code for one fixed cell at the top and then list of items in below in a single tableview, I am able to load the data from firestore database, but the first item in from the database is not shown, it is kind of hidden behind the fixed "detailscell", rest the fixed cell and all other items from the database shows up, how to fix that?

```
  override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       // print(posts)
        return posts.count

    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0 && details1.count > 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailsCell") as! DetailsCellInHomeScreen

            cell.set(details: details1[indexPath.row])
            return cell
        } else if posts.count > (indexPath.row - 1) {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell

            cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row - 1])
            return cell
        } else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `section header`

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini sorry, I am new to swift can guide me with example , I will be very grateful for that

Comment: Hey, did you see my answer? I have posted an answer as an example as you asked.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I tried to use it but I was not successful, I referred your and other examples but could not get the thing done, can you provide the code that could be implemented, i will be grateful for that

Answer (score 0):

`TableView` has a function like below:

```
// MARK: - Headers and Footers
extension MyTableViewController {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return MyCustomView()
    }
}
```

You can use this function to return any view you want as a **section header**. Also note that `sectionHeader` views are sticky in default style tableView (not **grouped style!**). So you can use this as a advantage.

There are many tutorials [like this one](https://medium.com/@onurtuna/custom-section-header-for-uitableview-4a6d91ce906c) on the internet to follow and learn *how to build a custom section section header for UITableView*

Answer (score 0):

You should add header on the table view:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       // print(posts)
        return posts.count

    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell

            cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row - 1])
            return cell
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50))

        let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect.init(x: 5, y: 5, width: headerView.frame.width-10, height: headerView.frame.height-10)
        label.text = "A Label on detailsCell"
        headerView.addSubview(label)

        return headerView
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
```

if the tableView has several section you can realize the section with `section: Int` object

`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?` uses for create the header view and  `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat` uses for set header height